# ios UISearchDisplayController dismiss when scroll result table view

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I used `UISearchDisplayController` to implement Search function. My main controller A has a `tableview` and I added `UISearchBar` to its `tableheaderview`.

I assigned:

```
 searchDisplayController.searchResultsDatasource = controllerA;
 searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = controllerA;
```

When I click on uiSearchBar, it show `searchDisplayController` as normal, and search works right, no problem. But when I scroll `resultTableView` on `searchDisplayController`, it dismiss `searchDisplayController` and return to controller A. Why I can't scroll?

As I thinking, `searchDisplayController` use `tableView` of controller A, and when I scroll, `searchDisplayController` is auto resign active. How can I don't allow `searchDisplayController` resign active?

Comment: Did you figure something out? I'm experiencing the same odd behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you make the same mistake with me. when we scroll the `searchResultsTableView`, this delegate method `-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` will be called.

So if you put the line below into the method, that'll be happened just like you said.
 `[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];`